# Fill a gap in a vector file using ArcMap without creating topological problems

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a shapefile and for some reason it has two holes. I want to fill them. Another post suggested using the remove ring function that's on the edit part. This worked only for one of the holes and I don't know why.

[image: Image before the Delete Ring]

[image: Image After the Delete Ring]

Comment: There's a bunch of ways to do this, including doing a Union with a bounding rectangle (and deleting the edge polygon) and converting to file geodatabase and using a topology.

Comment: Do you want to "fill" them with new polygons (and keep them) or make them part of the largest abutting polygon?  To create new polygons I'd use the autocomplete polygon tool although you could trace it too.  To make it part of the largest abutting polygon you could merge the ones you  created with the autopolygon tool, each with its largest the abutting polygon.

Comment: It failed, because it is not a hole but boundary of a bigger one. Just use Auto-complete polygon in editing session and merge it with parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the Edit Vertices tool in the Editor toolbar.

Clip on the polygon with the selection tool in the editing toolbar and use the Delete Vertex in Edit Vertices to select and delete the vertices that make up the hole.

[image]

Comment: Had to delete each vertice one by one but it worked! Thanks